# How do I achieve this effect in Gimp or Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

Anyways, please does anyone know how to achieve this "textured effect" (don't really know what its called.
Featured on this banner.

I know it's basically a transparent purple layer with some kind of image at the bottom.
I just can't quite figure out which exactly.

[image: web banner]

Comment: I don't understand what you're after.. the purple gradient striped background or the cast shadow under it? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Billy Kerr has so correctly outlined doesn't lend itself to sharing a HD image of file... He's saying you set up a simple gradient fill on one layer, create a new layer above, and then create a simple pattern fill on that layer with diagonal lines. In Photoshop, you would choose Edit>Fill, and in the subsequent pulldown for what you fill with, move from colour to Pattern. Photoshop ships with a boatload of patterns to begin with, and what Billy is saying is that this is just a basic diagonal line pattern which is in the Web Patterns library already with generic Photoshop.

Here's what that looks like in process:

[image]

Once you have that pattern fill on the layer above your purple gradient, you can choose one of many methods to get  your overlay effect: as Billy suggested, you can invert and use normal transparency, or you can (as I did) leave the pattern fill as-is and choose the Multiply transparency mode, in my example set to 25%.

The nice thing about this approach is that it remains easy to reapply the gradient on the underlying layer with either a different direction (as shown in your envato examples) or a different set of colour stops, all whilst keeping the same graphic language by dint of your pattern fill over the top: perfect for multiple related pieces.

Comment: Can't believe you took the stress to write all this ...Thanks a mill !! Really appreciate this :)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a simple gradient, with the "stripes 48x48" pattern fill on a new layer, inverted, reduced opacity, then rotated -45 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how I may go about creating this pattern in gimp or Photoshop or preferably an Hd image of the file will do wonders :) thanks

Comment: @user122061 HD is a video format. It's not really used in Photoshop or GIMP for still images. Just create the image bigger, with more pixels. A typical HD video image is 1920 x 1080 px.  As for how to do it, I already covered that in my answer, and the other answer already goes into more detail.